# How to link multiple wx.Dialogs in wxPython

Tags: python, wxpython

I want to make a game in wxPython (no other modules) and I want to make it so that you can enter some values in popup screens before the game starts, and then the game will be drawn on a canvas which in turn is drawn on a panel, which is bound to the main game.

I made the gamescreen with all fancy stuff (works solo)
I made the input screens
But I cannot link them.

How do I start the game so it will open a dialog box, then on the closure of it open another one, and then open the game ?

I tried the following, but it will not open my canvas:

```
# makes a game by showing 2 dialogs
# after dialogs have been answered, starts the game by drawing the canvas.

# imports  
import wx
import Speelveld3

# globals
SCRWIDTH = 950
SCRHEIGHT = 700

# dialogbox class
class MyDialog1(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.username = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.okButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK")

class MyDialog2(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.canvasWidth = wx.TextCtrl(self)
        self.okButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK")

# main class
class Game(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, -1, title='My game', size=(SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT))
        self.username = ""
        self.canvasWidth = 10
        # hide the frame for now
        self.Hide()

    def OnInit(self):
        #Make your dialogs
        dlg1 = MyDialog1(self)
        #if the user pressed "OK" (i.e. NOT "Cancel" or any other button you might add)
        if dlg1.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #get the username from the dialog
            self.username = dlg1.username.GetValue()
        #clean up the dialog (AFTER you get the username)
        dlg1.Destroy()

        dlg2 = MyDialog2(self)
        #if the user pressed "OK" (i.e. NOT "Cancel" or any other button you might add)
        if dlg2.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
            #get the username from the dialog
            self.canvasWidth = dlg2.canvasWidth.GetValue()
        #clean up the dialog (AFTER you get the username)
        dlg2.Destroy()



        # Now that you have your settings, Make the gameboard
        # THIS PART IS STILL BROKEN!
        # I can paste the whole board class (structure of it is taken from the tetris tutorial)
        # but that seems a bit much tbh...
        self.gameBoard = Board.Board(self)
        self.gameBoard = SetFocus()
        self.gameBoard.start()

        self.Centre()
        self.Show(True) #show the frame





if __name__ == '__main__':
# how can I start the game here?
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Game()
    board = Speelveld3.Speelveld(frame)
    board.start()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. There are no `wx.Dialog` objects in your code. Did you forget to include some code?

Answer (score 1):

In your OnInit you just need to call your dialogs and show them modally BEFORE you create your Board instance. Then it should work correctly.

**EDIT (6-28-12):** Here's some code:

```
import wx

########################################################################
class MyDlg(wx.Dialog):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, None, title="I'm a dialog!")

        lbl = wx.StaticText(self, label="Hi from the panel's init!")
        btn = wx.Button(self, id=wx.ID_OK, label="Close me")

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(lbl, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(btn, 0, wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MyPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        # show a custom dialog
        dlg = MyDlg()
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)

    def OnPaint(self, evt):
        pdc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        try:
            dc = wx.GCDC(pdc)
        except:
            dc = pdc
        rect = wx.Rect(0,0, 100, 100)
        for RGB, pos in [((178,  34,  34), ( 50,  90)),
                         (( 35, 142,  35), (110, 150)),
                         ((  0,   0, 139), (170,  90))
                         ]:
            r, g, b = RGB
            penclr   = wx.Colour(r, g, b, wx.ALPHA_OPAQUE)
            brushclr = wx.Colour(r, g, b, 128)   # half transparent
            dc.SetPen(wx.Pen(penclr))
            dc.SetBrush(wx.Brush(brushclr))
            rect.SetPosition(pos)
            dc.DrawRoundedRectangleRect(rect, 8)

########################################################################
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Example frame")

        # show a MessageDialog
        style = wx.OK|wx.ICON_INFORMATION
        dlg = wx.MessageDialog(parent=None, 
                               message="Hello from the frame's init", 
                               caption="Information", style=style)
        dlg.ShowModal()
        dlg.Destroy()

        # create panel
        panel = MyPanel(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MyFrame()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Ok, i got that, but can you give me some example code how to make a message dialog first (cause that needs to be bound to a frame too right), and then run the rest of the code ?

Answer (score 1):

You've [double posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235944/how-do-i-start-a-wxpython-program-with-a-dialogbox-then-pop-another-dialog-and), and the lack of any `wx.Dialog` in your sample code suggests to me that you haven't even looked at a tutorial yet, but I will give you the benefit of the doubt.

First, if you want to return information from a dialog, the easiest way is to define a [custom dialog](http://wiki.wxpython.org/AnotherTutorial#Custom_dialogs). Define a new class that inherits from `wx.Dialog` and then set it up just like you would a normal panel or a frame. It seems to me that you will need two of these. They'll look something like this:

```
class MyDialog1(wx.Dialog):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Dialog.__init__(self, parent)

        self.username = wx.TextCtrl(self) #this is where users will enter their username

        self.okButton = wx.Button(self, wx.ID_OK, "OK") #Note that I'm using wx.ID_OK. This is important
```

Now, for the logic you want. Pretty much every object in wxPython that you actually see has the functions `Show()` and `Hide()` (API [here](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.Window-class.html#Show)). You don't want to show your frame until AFTER the dialogs are finished, so in your `__init__()`, call `Hide()`. I'm also initializing a variable, `username`, which is where I will store the data from my dialog.

```
class Game(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=(SCRWIDTH, SCRHEIGHT))
        self.username = ""

        self.Hide() #don't show the frame just yet
        #self.Hide() is the exact same as self.Show(False)
```

Now, for your dialogs. Like Mike Driscoll suggested, you call your dialogs BEFORE making your canvas. `wx.Dialogs` are launched using `ShowModal()`. By setting the ID of `self.okButton` to the constant `wx.ID_OK`, wxPython recognizes that the dialog should be closed after the button in clicked. You should also be aware of `wx.ID_CANCEL`.

```
def OnInit(self):
    #Make your dialogs
    dlg1 = MyDialog1(self)
    if dlg1.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:
        #if the user pressed "OK" (i.e. NOT "Cancel" or any other button you might add)
        self.username = dlg1.username.GetValue() #get the username from the dialog
    dlg1.Destroy() #clean up the dialog (AFTER you get the username)

    #do this again for your second dialog

    #Now that you have your settings, Make the gameboard
    self.gameBoard = Board.Board(self)
    self.gameBoard = SetFocus()
    self.gameBoard.start()

    self.Centre()
    self.Show(True) #show the frame
```

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I indeed double posted, because I thought I didn't formulate my problem right. Anyway, I did spend hours and hours working on Dialogs, and the problem is that I do not know how to bind them properly to my panel of frame. Also, I do not know how to start the canvas at the moment. (I used the tetris tutorial as guidance to setup this framework zetcode.com/wxpython/thetetrisgame) At the moment I also keep messing up the bottom part (if __name__ == '__main__': etc) I want to post my new code here, but i dont know how...

Comment: If i use this code in the bottom of my game class, it will run the canvas, but not the dialogs before it: if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame = Game()
    board = Speelveld3.Speelveld(frame)
    board.start()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

Comment: @Dieseltjuh use the `Edit` button at the botton of your question to add more information. Also, you need to indent your entire `onInit()` function. Right now it is too far to the left so it isn't actually part of `Game`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, i fixed the code to the new version. Please note that the game starts right away without showing dialogs.

Comment: @Dieseltjuh Because you start the board in your `main` program. Remove that. You sould only call your board from inside `Game`. Also, you never call `onInit()`. So either call `onInit()` or merge it with `__init__()`.